# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Mathematics Educators's [first moderator election](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, and the votes have been tallied, resulting in the new moderator :

[image: Chris Cunningham]

Chris will be joining [the existing crew](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank Chris for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4771089110532096/0).

Comment: Congrats on a well deserved position. And a clean campaign.

Comment: Thank you to all the candidates that volunteered, and welcome to the mod-team Chris.

Comment: Congratulations, Chris Cunningham♦, and thank you for volunteering to take on the duties of moderator.

Comment: Congratulations.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to have you.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you!

- I have a lot to learn,
- I think the original moderators are doing a great job,
- I think both of the other candidates would have been excellent, and
- I will do some good work here.

As the question says, assistance and advice is welcome - in particular I greatly appreciated the interactions I had with invested users during the election process.

I look forward to serving the community and the site!